# How modify guvnor in kie workbench

Tags: drools, rules, guvnor, kie-wb

I have a question. 
I have a modified version of guvnor 5.2 (by me). I would substitute the actual version of guvnor in Kie-wb with mine. 
Can i do this?. 
Eventually there is a folder where I can modify guvnor's files. I don't found guvnor folder in kie project. 
Otherwise how i can modify the menu to add my functionality in existing kie?

thanks to all 
I'm sorry for the bad english :)

Answer (score 0):

KIE Workbench is the new version of Guvnor. Therefore old versions of Guvnor are not compatible. They're certainly not valid for manipulating Drools 6 rules. You will need to make customisations to KIE Workbench, similar to what you previously changed in Guvnor.

Comment: thank you, my problem is that kie workbench is different from Guvnor and I don't know where put the hands XD

Comment: It might be worth updating your question to explain exactly what customisations you would like to make. That way, someone might be able to provide a more useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can find the sources of the whole kie platform in these repositories: 
BPM side: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/jbpm-console-ng
Drools Side: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/drools-wb/
Generic things: https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-common/

Distribution, (which means the final kie-wb that you downloaded is built based on the code in this repository, that basically add all the other repositories dependencies): https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-distributions

So for example if you want to add a new entry on the menu of the kie-wb you should clone that last repository and modify the ShowcaseEntryPoint class that defines the menus. If you want to change something in the BPM screens you should clone the jbpm console ng repo, change the screens and then build the kie-wb app that is inside the kie-wb-distributions repo to get your changes included in the main distribution .

Hope it helps!